# How are UIMotionEffect and CoreMotion different?

Tags: ios, core-motion, uimotioneffect

I am very much enjoying some better results achieved with `UIMotionEffect` subclass than listening to `CMMotionManager`. Using `CoreMotion` usually gives inaccuracies as also saw many people complain about it through the web.

I cannot find any explanation though to how these differ, in terms of which sensors are used, or what manipulation is used on the output of these sensors that explains the different results that I am experiencing.

`UIMotionEffect` by Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimotioneffect

`CMMotionManager` by Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager

Now while its obvious that `CMMotionManager` gives you much more functionality like Gyro, acceleration and more, I am mostly asking about roll/pitch that I can either get as a `UIOffset` from overriding `UIMotionEffect` or get it from the `CMDeviceMotion.attitude`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not the right place to ask this question, however I'll try to answer you.

`CoreMotion` is an API to access raw values of the sensors from the accelerometer, the gyroscope, the magnetometer and other higher level indicators. It can be configured with different update profiles (from very high refresh rate to economic, power saving refresh rate).

With `UIMotionEffect` you can move/animate your views along horizontal and vertical axis rotations of your device. It's mostly used for creating parallax effects like the background moving on the springboard *(the home screen)*. You also have to subclass this class or use the already made `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect`.

`UIMotionEffect` is made for quick, subtle effects on your UI, and can be used out of the box with small energy footprint, when `CoreMotion` is more suited in intensive gyroscope usage like in games with motion controls.

Oh, and `UIMotionEffect` is permanently centering the view, so when you rotate your phone and stand still on the side, it will gently slide back to the center to match your new position, not very usable in games.

Comment: Thanks. I would love to hear about the way you can configure the update profiles on the UIMotionEffect. I looked for something like that but couldn't locate it

Comment: @Eyzuky after looking, it seems you're right, `UIMotionEffect` seems to not be configurable. I was pretty sure I already done that. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Great, thanks for looking into it. I hope they let us configure it in the future

Comment: I guess it's designed to have minimal impact on battery life. I don't think they will.

Comment: Well I would love to see a pause option, or a recenter function that I can control by myself.. that will probably not impact battery

Comment: I would also want to have a threshold for speed of movement.. that I can filter subtle movements.